# Optionally attach extra data to a type

Tags: ocaml

Suppose I have a module with a bunch of recursive type declarations and there is already plenty of consumers that do `open M` and then work with `type1`, `type2` and `type3`.

```
module M = struct
  type type1 = 
    | T1_Case1 of string * type2
    | T1_Case2 of type3
  and type2 = type3 list
  and type3 = 
    | T3_Case1 of type1
    | T3_Case2 of int
end
```

During one of processing steps there is a need to augment one of more of these types into types augmented with some extra data, somewhat similar to:

```
  type type1 = 
    | T1_Case1 of string * type2
    | T1_Case2 of type3
  and type2 = type3 list
  and type3_ = 
    | T3_Case1 of type1
    | T3_Case2 of int
  and type3 = extra_data * type3_
```

Is it possible to achieve this without involving external codegen tools or breaking existing code?

The latter option rules out a possibility to convert `M` into a functor parameterized with annotation type:

```
(* won't work since all places that used to deal with type3 should be updated *)
module type AnnotationT = sig type t end

module M_F(Annotation: AnnotationT) = struct
  type type1 = 
    | T1_Case1 of string * type2
    | T1_Case2 of type3
  and type2 = type3 list
  and type3_ = 
    | T3_Case1 of type1
    | T3_Case2 of int
  and type3 = Annotation.t * type3_
end

module M = struct 
 include M_F(struct type t = unit end)
end
```

My guess that I need something like this (does not work since I cannot use functor application in type declaration):

```
module type EnvelopeType = sig type t end

module type AnnotatorType = functor(Envelope: EnvelopeType) -> sig
  type t
end

module Annotated_M(Annotator: AnnotatorType) = struct
  type tt = T: Annotator().t
  type type1 = 
    | T1_Case1 of string * type2
    | T1_Case2 of type3
  and type2 = type3 list
  and type3_ = 
    | T3_Case1 of type1
    | T3_Case2 of int
  (* does not work *)
  and type3 = Annotator(struct type t = type3_ end).t
end

module M = struct
  include Annotated_M(functor (Envelope: EnvelopeType) -> struct
    type t = Envelope.t
  end)
end

module M2 = struct
  include Annotated_M(functor (Envelope: EnvelopeType) -> struct
    type t = extra_data * Envelope.t
  end)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt can be made to work if you switch from functor to parameterized type like so:

```
module type AnnotatorType = sig

  type 'a annotated

end

module Annotated_M(Annotator: AnnotatorType) = struct

  type type1 = 
    | T1_Case1 of string * type2
    | T1_Case2 of type3
  and type2 = type3 list
  and type3_ = 
    | T3_Case1 of type1
    | T3_Case2 of int
  and type3 = type3_ Annotator.annotated

end

module M = struct
  include Annotated_M(struct
    type 'a annotated = 'a
  end)
end

module M2 = struct
  include Annotated_M(struct
    type 'a annotated = extra_data * 'a
  end)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an instance of the [X-Y](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) problem, and although there are technical workarounds for the problem `Y` the problem `X` will still persist. Let me elaborate on it later, but now I would suggest several technical solutions.

1. You can parametrize a functor that defines your type with a type for each branch (or some branches) of the defined type, e.g.,

   ```
   module type Variants = sig 
     type t1
     type t2
     ...
   end

   module Define(V : Variants) = struct
     type t = V of t1 | V of t2 ...
   end
   ```
2. You can use a parametric type instead:

   ```
   type ('a,'b,..) t = A of 'a | B of 'b
   ```

Both of these solutions are a sort of an abuse of data constructors as they trade off the efficiency for flexibility.

Now let me elaborate a little more on the `X` problem. My wild guess is that you're trying to represent some transformation of languages (i.e., some intermediate representations, DSL, etc). And you have a pair of representations that are quite isomorphic to each other but they define different types and the problem that you perceive is the code repetition that is involved in *definitions* of those two types. The code repetition is a usual indicator of a missed abstraction. The type definitions in OCaml doesn't introduce abstractions, they define a representation of a type. Abstractions are introduced by module types and are implemented with modules, that use a particular representation of a type. Thus, what you really need to solve the `X` problem, is a proper abstraction. In our case, relying on the tagged embedding forces us to disclose our representation and makes it concrete instead of abstract. This is, sometimes, convenient, but is rather fragile, and soon will lead to a code repetition. A possible solution, is the [tagless final style](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/index.html), that allows us to define extensible abstractions, without sticking to a particular representation.